# how can i use inner join in solr

Tags: join, solr

SELECT A.ioTDeviceKind, B.resourceRiskLevelLowCount, B.resourceRiskLevelMiddleCount, B.resourceRiskLevelHighCount FROM ioTDevice AS A JOIN resourcelogCurrent AS B ON A.ioTDeviceKind = B.ioTDeviceKind WHERE A.resourceId = 'airconditinal'

or

SELECT A.ioTDeviceKind, B.resourceRiskLevelLowCount, B.resourceRiskLevelMiddleCount, B.resourceRiskLevelHighCount FROM ioTDevice AS A INNER JOIN resourcelogCurrent AS B ON A.ioTDeviceKind = B.ioTDeviceKind WHERE A.resourceId = 'airconditinal'

but the result is null.
there is no error, but the result always is null,
where i user left join, there is no error..
please help me , how can i use inner join in solr??

Comment: Does it work when you do a LEFT JOIN instead? Generally joins hasn't been supported in the SQL interface - at least not when attempting to select results from both sides of the join. The Solr version might also be relevant here - but the reference docs currently say nothing about implementing JOINs as far as I can see.

Comment: yes the left join work well. but the right or left or inner is not working ..